# Woocommerce No Sidebar on product-category pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, sidebar

If you compare a shop page I'm building

https://inflite.cc/typeone/shop/

and the category page

https://inflite.cc/typeone/product-category/accessories/

you can see that the wordpress categories pages has no sidebars. This doesn't appear to be a theme options setting that I can see for archive / category pages so I wondered if there was another way to add this in using functions.php or which php theme file would likely be used for archive pages?

I notice a file called "archive-product.php" which has the following

```
<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_sidebar hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
?>
```

but this isn't injecting the sidebar onto my product-category pages

Thanks

---

sidebar.php

```
<?php

if ( (! function_exists( 'cs_framework_init' ) && is_active_sidebar('shop_sidebar')) || (is_shop() && cs_get_option('enable_sidebar_ecommerce')) || is_product() && cs_get_option('enable_sidebar_ecommerce_detail')) { ?>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <?php if ( ! function_exists( 'dynamic_sidebar' ) || ! dynamic_sidebar( 'shop_sidebar' ) ); ?>
</div>
<?php }


?>
```

Comment: Do you have sidebar.php in your theme ? also have u add add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' ); ?

Comment: @MartinMirchev I've found sidebar.php (code added above). Looks like its saying that if it's a shop page or a product page, whats the syntax for product catagories? is it `is_product_category()` ?

Comment: Yes is_product_category() is correct - https://woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/